# Problems with reading and writing a text file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

**This answer was solved by doing `print (file.read())`**

I have a project called 'PyDOS'. I recently discovered that you can read and write files in Python, I implemented this and the writing bit worked. But when trying the read part, it gives a syntax. The code that's messing up the reading part is:

```
print file.read
```

This is the code with the first error:

```
def textviewer():
   print ("Text Viewer.")
   file_name = input("Enter a text file to view: ")
   file = open(file_name, "r")
   print file.read #This returns 'Syntax Error' when pressing F5
   input("Press enter to close")

def edit(): #However, the writing function works just fine.
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        print ("EDIT")
        print ("-------------")
        print ("Note: Naming this current document the same as a different document will replace the other document with this one.")
        filename = input("Plese enter a file name.")
        file = open(filename, "w")
        print ("Now, Write 5 lines.")
        line1 = input()
        line2 = input()
        line3 = input()
        file.write(line1)
        file.write("\n")
        file.write(line2)
        file.write("\n")
        file.write(line3)
        file.close()
        print ("File saved!")
        time.sleep(3)
```

It returns syntax error, I tried `file.read()` but instead showed:

```
<built-in method read of _io.TextIOWrapper object at 0x10ada08>
```

Comment: `print` is not a statement but a function, and `file.read` is a method you need to *call*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<built-in method read of _io.TextIOWrapper object at 0x10ada08>
```

That's the string representation of a function. What you want isn't the function itself, but rather to call the function.

In other words, you want `file.read()` instead of `file.read`.

Also, in Python 3.x, `print` is a function, not a keyword, so you want `print(file.read())`, not `print file.read()`.

Incidentally, [`file` is the name of a built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=file#file) (albeit a deprecated one), so you should use a different variable name.

Comment: I did file.read() but when pressing F5 it says syntax error and highlights 'file'

Comment: Ah, wait, I see it: in Python 3.x, `print` is a function. That's why `print file.read()` would fail in 3.x but not 2.x. You want `print(file.read())`.

Comment: Ok, I type in file.read(). When pressing F5, a popup appears saying invalid syntax. The error is located: file.read()

Comment: Put yourself in my shoes: how does that description help anyone else? We can't see your screen.

Comment: Regardless, as I said above, `print` is a function in Python 3.x.